# Integrating CKEditor with Rails 3.1 Asset Pipline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ckeditor, asset-pipeline

I'm new to the Asset Pipeline, having just migrated over from Rails 3.0. I'm trying to get CKEditor into the pipeline, but all the gems for it are really unclear about how they work, and have little or no usage instructions.

I would prefer to do this without using a gem, since it seems that all I have to do is drop the source files into the `vendor/assets` directory and then include them in `application.js`. I've tried that, however, when I precompile and push to production, it seems that some of the files aren't being found (`editor.css`, for example), and the editor doesn't show up at all (just blank area).

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require ckeditor/ckeditor
//= require_self
```

That's with the source files in `vendor/assets/javascript/ckeditor/`, and is pointing to `ckeditor.js`. I'm just not sure where to go from here. This code works fine in development but does not work in production. I am running `rake assets:precompile` before adding and committing to git, and then pushing to heroku. [image: Here's a screenshot of the client-side errors that occur]

Comment: Since there are a few people watching this question - With Rails 3.1+, CKEditor integrates pretty easily with the Asset Pipeline - you just have to tell your application to include it (in manifest files or application.rb). There is a nice gem that organizes everything for you: ckeditor_rails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are on Rails 3.1.0, you should upgrade to 3.1.1. In this version the precompile rake task compiles assets into both original and digested filenames. This is so third-party code that is not pipeline aware will still work.

You will need to add the ckeditor directory and all its child directories to the precompile array so that the precompile task knows to compile them.

`config.assets.precompile += your_files`

your_files can be an array of files, regexs or Procs - whatever is need to capture the names of the ckeditor files. I don't have ckeditor handy to work out what needs to go in precompile, so others might appreciate it if you post what you come up with!

One thing to watch is that if you have far-future headers set for the /assets directory on your webserver, you'll need to exclude the CKeditor directory. Because those files won't be fingerprinted, there may be issues when you update CKeditor with some clients not getting the updated code because they have a cached copy that marked to only expire some time in the future.

Answer (score 28):

I got this working (deployed on Heroku), by:

1. Including the ckeditor code in vendor/assets/javascripts/ckeditor
2. Adding `config.assets.precompile += ['ckeditor/*']` to my production.rb
3. Setup your ckeditor base path in the application.html.erb `var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/assets/ckeditor/';` before the include of the application.js
4. In application.js, include `//= require ckeditor/ckeditor`

Comment: Not as bad as I had feared :)

Comment: A++ Well done. You saved my day. That should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 10):

Bite the bullet and use a gem. Two options here:

### CKEditor Engine

https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor.

This runs as an engine and includes its own mountable CKEditor in assets. It also exposes Ckeditor.assets which you can add to your assets path. This references all the images, plugins, language files and miscellaneous little bits of junk that CKEditor requires.

It has a shot at handling image uploads and it also integrates nicely with **ActiveAdmin**.

### CKEditor Rails

https://github.com/tsechingho/ckeditor-rails

This does less, you include it in your asset pipeline and it does the rest for you. Nice and simple and sufficient for all basic use cases.

### Upshot

I have used both of these on live projects and both do the job. Use the former if you plan on using ActiveAdmin and you want a smooth ride.  Use the latter if you prefer minimal.

CKEditor is pretty ugly. Keep it at arms length, then when you need to upgrade you can swap it out for another.

Comment: Agreed - I posted this almost a year ago, and now the ckeditor gem is definitely the way to go, although I prefer [this one](https://github.com/tsechingho/ckeditor-rails) because it doesn't try to do too much.

Comment: Agreed, I like that one too. Looks a lot more light weight.

Comment: I've modified the answer to include the CKEditor Rails gem.

Comment: I used the CKEditor Rails gem in a live project and it does the job nicely.

Comment: Thanks! I found the second option works far better for me :-)

Comment: Extremely slow and unresponsive dev https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/397

Comment: Culture of entitlement. It's open source, fork it and fix it yourself. Don't expect someone else working in their spare time to do your job for you for free.

Answer (score 1):

Have similar issue. For me it was fixed by overriding default precompile task (I used Rails 4 and CkEditor 4).

1. Add to application.rb `config.assets.precompile += ['ckeditor/*']`
2. In application.js `//= require ckeditor/init`
3. Create file `lib/tasks/precompile_hook` and paste text from this answer [Precompile hook](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/316)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, I've adjusted fallback in production for the assets which had not digest until it will be fixed:

config/environments/production.rb

```
 config.assets.compile = true
```

Answer (score 0):

what about ckeditor_assets directory in /public ? uploaded photos and attachments go to those directories, as defined by default in app/models/ckeditor/[attachment.rb,photo.rb]

ckeditor_assets is outside of assets and images/files are not accessible (url like http://yourdomain.com/ckeditor_assets/pictures/1/file.jpg will not work, but the file is there)

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time getting the [ckeditor_rails](https://github.com/tsechingho/ckeditor-rails) gem to work; maybe I can save some time for others trying to do the same.

The gem worked just fine out-of-the-box in development, but when deployed to production using precompiled assets under Phusion Passenger it did not.  It was clear to me that the problem was that it was looking for assets under:

```
http://myhost.com/assets/ckeditor
```

where in fact it needed to be looking under:

```
http://myhost.com/my_app_name/assets/ckeditor
```

It was also clear to me that I needed somehow to set:

```
var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/my_app_name/assets/ckeditor'
```

but no matter where or how I tried to do this, it wouldn't take.

Finally, I found on this key sentence on the [gem wiki](https://github.com/tsechingho/ckeditor-rails/wiki/Work-with-asset-host):

> You can create app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/basepath.js.erb to
>   have your own CKEDITOR_BASEPATH.

I created the file as specified (alongside my config.js file for configuring the editor), added my CKEDITOR_BASEPATH setting to the file, re-compiled my assets, and all was good.

Answer (score 0):

In your config/development.rb make sure to set

> config.assets.precompile += ['ckeditor/*']

as well as set

> config.assets.debug = true