# How to get ckeditor resources to compile and load in Rails 3.1 asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ckeditor, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to use CKEditor in a Rails 3.1 app.   I have the ckeditor directory in app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/,  with extraneous stuff like the uncompressed and modularized source removed.

It works fine in development.  In production or staging environments, ckeditor can't find it's own files: config.js,  lang/en.js  skins/kama/editor.css.    I can see that these files are not being precompiled, which makes sense since the asset pipeline by default won't include or precompile anything that matches /.css/ or /.js/.

According to the rails docs and [previous answers like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914924/integrating-ckeditor-with-rails-3-1-asset-pipline), adding the files I need to config.assets.precompile is supposed to be the solution.   However, despite extensive effort I cannot figure out what format I am supposed to use with config.assets.precompile.  It's not documented and no examples are given.

**I've tried explicitly adding the files by name:**

```
config.assets.precompile << ['config.js', 'en.js', 'editor.css']
```

**I've tried adding regexes that will match the files:**

```
config.assets.precompile << [ /.*config\.js/, /.*en.js/, /.*editor.css/ ]
```

**I've tried explicitly adding the full paths:**

```
config.assets.precompile << File.join(Rails.root, 'app', 'assets', 'javascripts', 'ckeditor', 'config.js')
(etc...)
```

In all of these cases (and everything else I've tried), running rake assets:precompile still fails to move the files I need into public/assets.   All the images and such go, but not the three javascript and/or css files CKEditor needs to run.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Where are you appending to config.assets.precompile?

Answer (score 2):

I've run into similar issues. I ended up using CKEditor without asset pipeline :)

After several gems tried, none worked ok in production environment. I ended up putting ckeditor into `public` folder of the app. That skips the asset pipeline process completely and ckeditor works just fine in production as well. No assets pre-compilation though...

Using rails 3.1, CKEditor 4.1. Although this is an old thread, maybe this could help someone...

Update: Also, if you're testing on your local production environment, don't forget to set `serve_static_assets` to true in `config/environments/production.rb`

Answer (score 2):

For me it was fixed by overriding default precompile task (I used Rails 4 and CkEditor 4).

1. Add to application.rb `config.assets.precompile += ['ckeditor/*']`
2. In application.js `//= require ckeditor/init`
3. Create file `lib/tasks/precompile_hook.rake` and paste text from this answer [Precompile hook](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/316)

Comment: The rake file name should be "lib/tasks/precompile_hook.rake".

Comment: This works. However, I am not seeing any images on the toolbar. It looks like icons.png and some other icon image files are missing. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some additional info? Version of rails and ckeditor. Are this images precompiled or not?

Comment: @YosepKim, I'm running into the same issue. I know this is pretty old, but did you ever figure out what the issue was with the toolbar icons?

Comment: @AlecSanger I think the only way for me to get it to work was to pre-compile the asset before pushing live. I actually didn't even use the rake task described in the answer. To pre-compile (you may already know this but just in case), run the following: RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in your code. The precompile attribute is an array.

You can append a single item to the array like this:

```
config.assets.precompile << 'name_of_file.ext'
```

If your values are in an array then you have to ADD the array.

```
config.assets.precompile += [ /.*config\.js/, /.*en.js/, /.*editor.css/ ]
```

If you append then you'd have an array nested inside the precompile array, which is ignored.