# Rails - CKEditor - No routes matches lang/fr.js and editor.css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I'm trying to use CKeditor in production, but it always fails.

The log :

```
Started GET "/backend/articles/lang/fr.js?t=C6HH5UF" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-12 20:52:40 +0100

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/backend/articles/lang/fr.js"):
```

And

```
Started GET "/backend/articles/skins/kama/editor.css?t=C6HH5UF" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-12 20:52:40 +0100
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/backend/articles/skins/kama/editor.css"):
```

In my prodcution.rb :

```
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = true
```

I've tried explicitly adding the files according to this question =>           [How to get ckeditor resources to compile and load in Rails 3.1 asset pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023523/how-to-get-ckeditor-resources-to-compile-and-load-in-rails-3-1-asset-pipeline)

```
  config.assets.precompile += [ /.*config\.js/, /.*fr.js/, /.*editor.css/ ]
```

But it fails... It means that textareas are not displayed.
Does somebody have an idea ?
THanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

this might help you, try to add like this:

in your production.rb:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['ckeditor/skins/kama/editor.css', 'ckeditor/lang/fr.js', 'ckeditor/skins/kama/editor.css']
```

and in the layout, add this line in the HEAD tag of html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/assets/ckeditor/';
</script>
```