# Rails ckeditor Invalid CSS after "*": expected "{", was "html .cke_uicol..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems, ckeditor

I'm updating an app to rails 3.1 and I'm getting this error when precompiling my assets, I've updated ckeditor to 4.0.2 because according to this [Github Issue](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/188) that will fix it but the error is still there. Do I have to do something after I update the gem?

Here's the full error:

```
Invalid CSS after "*": expected "{", was "html .cke_uicol..."

"html" may only be used at the beginning of a compound selector.
  (in /home/stanwinston/stanwinston/app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/_source/plugins/uicolor/yui/assets/yui.css)
```

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: If you cannot update to 3.2 (as @user1479606 suggests) and really need to make it work, it's possible to setup CKEditor in public folder (without gem). See [another topic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15667319/615434).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am going to catch some flak for this but, after trying to upgrade and blah blah blah 3 hours, here was how I fixed it:

Due to the complexity of my app, and the requirement to support IE 8, I was unable to readily change the rails or ckeditor version.  What I did instead was to fix the css included in the gem:

/opt/boxen/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ckeditor-3.7.1/vendor/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/plugins/uicolor/yui/assets/yui.css

There is a "*html" where you need a "* html", note the space.

Here are some related posts about the issue:
http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9411 and https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/188

Then I precompiled my assets locally, so that the asset compilation happened on my machine with the patched gem. I am not a fan of this method, but my client is not a fan of broken web forms, or longer hours spent updating libraries without adding any new features.

There is no point in submitting a pull request against the gem, since it is code from a 3rd party of a 3rd party and the gem has long since switched to rails 4 support.

Feel free to tell me I am wrong for X reason below.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also stumble upon the same situation but update my Rails version to 3.2+ solve the problem