# Integrating Rails 3.2 with CKEditor: Failed to load resource: Skins package

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ckeditor

I have a problem when integrating my Rails app with CKEditor. I had followed instructions that i got from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694917/integrating-ckeditor-with-rails-3-2) . I copied the extracted folder (ckeditor) to */assets/javascript* and I add a line like this on my page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/assets/ckeditor/';
</script>
```

But, when i opened my browser I got errors like this on my Javascript Console

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/assets/ckeditor/skins/office2003/skin.js?t=D3NA

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  http://localhost:3000/assets/ckeditor/skins/office2003/editor.css?t=D3NA
```

I use Rails 3.2 and downloaded the latest version of CKEditor 4.1.1

Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ah,, my bad, I did not add this following JS script on my page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor',
      {
        // Optional params:
        skin: 'office2003' // I change it to 'moono' and everything works well
        height: '300px'
      });
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

config.js:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
    config.extraPlugins = 'syntaxhighlight';
    config.skin = 'office2003'; //tested OK
    config.toolbar = 
   [..................]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The way it worked for me:

1. Download the skin from [Here](http://ckeditor.com/addons/skins/all).
2. Place it under `ckeditor/skins` folder, if you dont have `skins` folder then create one.
3. Add below line to `ckeditor/config.js` file.

   `CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
     config.skin = 'bootstrapck';
   }`
4. Add `//= require_tree ./ckeditor` to your application.js file.
   you might have to write `//= require_tree .` before `//= require_tree ./ckeditor`. I am not sure why but without this line other javascripts are not getting loaded properly. Also, if you change the order it won't load editor properly.